# Android Application : Background Image over Background Color

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, background-color

I am new to android development and am developing my first android application. I have the background color of the View set in the layout's xml as follows.

```
android:background="@+color/bgColor"
```

Now, i have a full sized transparent background image that i want to lay over the background and then other Elements over that image.

is there a way i can use both background color and background image in the same layout.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an ImageView with a background color:

```
<ImageView
    layout_width="match_parent"
    layout_height="match_parent"
    src="@drawable/myImage"
    background="@color/myBgColor" />
```

Another option is to set the background color in the root element of your layout, and keep the src in your ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `AppCompatImageView`. In this background color can be set using the below property.

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```